# Testfor item not working correctly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

No one seems to have answered this question from what I've seen, but here's the question. I have this command: `testfor @e[type=Item,x=-847,z=156]`. What happens is this will trigger for every item laying out, not just the ones whose coordinates -847, y, 156. Can someone please help me on this or tell my what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters will normally default to the sender's coordinates when not specified (the sender in this case being a command block). By specifying these parameters, all you're doing is changing what the origin is, but nothing more than that. The command will select all item entities, but sorting based on distance starting from the modified origin (where the unspecified `y` parameter becomes the command block's Y coordinate).

You must use `/execute` to change the origin to that of the intended targets (while being able to modify that new origin with `/execute`'s syntax), and you must also include a selection limiter such as `r` or `dx/dy/dz` to prevent selecting all around the world.

For example, the following will kill any item entities at the X and Z coordinate, replacing the Y coordinate with the item entity's Y value:

```
/execute @e[type=Item] -847 ~ 156 /kill @e[type=Item,c=1,dx=0]
```

Comment: For some reason, it keeps saying the entity UUID provided is in an invalid format. Could you help out on that a little please?

Comment: @Garhoogin That error simply means that no target was found. If you're running the command provided, you'll essentially never see the success message in the command block because it'd only last for a single tick before failing to find another target.

Comment: Oh. Would the coordinates be exact or just in a 1 block radius of the specified coordinates?

Comment: @Garhoogin With `dx=0`, the entire blockspace at the specified coordinates will be selected (unlike `r=0`, where the entity must reside at the exact center of the block).